# Netatalk authorizing with Windows Active Directory Clients

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, file-sharing, afp, netatalk

We have an Ubuntu server that we intend to use to share videos and other content over AFP to our client Macs. AFP works flawlessly by setting the allow list to one single user. The problem arises when we wish to make use of other users in our Windows Active directory.

My /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default file looks like this:

```
~/Videos  "Videos" allow:@staff-linux, computeradmin allowed_hosts:192.168.10.0/24,192.168.40.0/24  options:upriv,usedots
```

(Computeradmin is a local user on the machine, they can connect to the afp share).

We have added the Ubuntu server into the Active Directory domain using Likewise Open, and users can log in with their usernames via ssh.

How can we allow all the users in the 'Staff-Linux' active directory group to connect to this share?

Thanks in advance.

I originally posted this here on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/20ea91/netatalk_authorizing_with_windows_active/)